# conversion from a base type to other pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

i want to make a pointer of type double to point to a pointer of type int which points to another var:

```
 int x=23;
 int *f_var =&x;      
 double*l_ptr = (double *)f_var;
```

both of these pointers have the same address but when i display their values  f_var display the good one but l_ptr display a strange value. Why is this happens and i will be glad if you will explain me.Why they don't have the same value? If both of them are pointing to the same location and double can store an int why they have different values?

Comment: "i want to make a pointer of type double to point to a pointer of type int which points to another var: " ...what for?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?

Comment: This is a very bad idea. Even if it does what you intend on your system, you may get different results depending on the size of each type (afaik). You should include what your intent is; this seems like am xy problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "display their values"?   Printing the values of the pointers is a very different thing from dereferencing the pointers and printing the resulting values.  My hunch is you're doing the latter, and the result of that is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why are you even doing it like this?

Comment: i wanted to see if it works.It seems ,at first, strange that though they have the same address to point the value they store(dereference) is not the same.I wanted to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question itself is flawed, but I'll attempt to respond to a couple of aspects of it.

Firstly, an `int` is not a base type for a `double`.    Neither is a pointer to `int` a base type for a pointer to `double`.   So this question is mis-titled.

Second, there is no guarantee that a floating point type can store every value an `int` can.   In practice, that depends on the floating point representation (how many bits it uses to represent the mantissa).   It often turns out that a `float` or `double` can represent some of the values an `int` can, but not others (for which it stores a value that is an approximation).   This is part of the trade-off of a floating point variable being able to represent non-integral values over a larger range than an `int` can.

Third, your description "display their values" is ambiguous.   If you are doing

```
  std::cout << f_var << ' ' << l_ptr << '\n';
```

or (more explicitly, without relying on implicit conversions to void pointers)

```
  std::cout << (void *)f_var << ' ' << (void *)l_ptr << '\n';
```

the value of the pointers (i.e. the address they hold) will be printed.   In practice, the values output will typically be the same - it is their type that differs, not their value.   But the values of these pointers are the address in memory of the variable `x`, not the value of `x`.

Alternatively, if you are doing

```
  std::cout << *f_var << ' ' << *l_ptr << '\n';
```

the result is undefined behaviour, since `l_ptr` is being dereferenced as if it points to a `double`, despite pointing to an `int`.   The result of this can be anything (printing garbage, printing values you don't expect, reformatting your hard drive, anything).   In practice, it probably attempts to interpret the bits that make up an `int` (i.e. the variable `x`) as if they represent a floating point value.   Since the bits in an `int` have different meaning from the bits in a `double` (there is a mantissa and an exponent in floating point representations, which is why a `double` can represent values like `0.5E15` or `0.5E-3`) the same set of bits represents a different value.    There is also the wrinkle that, typically, a `double` consists of more bits than an `int` does - so, by printing in this way, your code is interpreting random memory to the right of `x` as data.

Comment: actually when i do   std::cout << f_var << ' ' << l_ptr << '\n';  the code compile and i see that both of them have the same address.And your second statements shows me the same result as first one. My question was for your thrid statement.That i want to know if i can do it and its implication.Thx

Comment: Yeah, okay.  I had a minor brain fart with that.   I'll correct the post shortly.

Comment: after searching i discover something "strict-aliasing rule".It has something to do with this pointers to other types?

Comment: Over-simplistically, dereferencing a cast of a variable from one type of pointer to a different type (as you have done here) is usually in violation of the strict aliasing rule.   That violation, in your case, is what causes dereferencing `l_ptr` to result in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, when you do that:

```
int x=23;
int *f_var = &x;      
double *l_ptr = (double *)f_var;
```

`l_ptr` isn't a "pointer of type double [which points] to a pointer of type int" (as you said) but a pointer to double which stores the address of an `int`. Dereferencing it is undefined behaviour.
<s>[Edit: actually, the cast from `int*` to `double*` is already undefined behaviour, so `l_ptr` may store something else than the address of `x`]</s>
[Edit: oops, no, you can "safely" reinterpret_cast from any pointer to any pointer/integral large enough to hold its value]

Dereferencing a pointer to double actually storing the address of a pointer to int isn't any better though<s>, assuming you achieve to assign that address to a pointer to double without causing undefined behaviour</s> (and a pointer of type double, is actually probably not a pointer, but i assumed you meant "pointer to double").

What you see when you output `*l_ptr* is probably the bitwise representation of`x`and probably some garbage data (because a`double`may be longer in memory than an`int`) interpreted as a double. However, it could as well be 42 or "you're doing weird things" (or a crash, or nothing at all): it is undefined behaviour, the compiler may generate anything he wants and still meet the C++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

An `int` and `double` are not stored the same way. For a start they're most likely different sizes in memory. But more importantly their bits are used in very different ways.

So quite simply: reintrepreting an int's memory as a double is nonsense and shouldn't be expected to show the same value.

If you were to do something like:

```
int a = 23;
double b = 23;
bool isSameBits = (memcmp(&a, &b, sizeof(a)) == 0);
```

That bool should indicate that they indeed don't use their bits the same way.

And `bool isSameSize = (sizeof(a) == sizeof(b));` would indicate if they're different sizes.

If you want to know more about the underlying details, then you could perhaps google for something like "memory layout of double".

Answer (score 0):

Then it is possible to make a pointer of a type to point to a different pointer of other type and when you dereference them to hold both of them the same value? I only want to know because as you saw i am a noob.